# Why is Set on Less Than an ALU operation

Tags: assembly, mips

Why is `slt` considered an ALU operation? I thought it will just do a subtract then get the **Z**ero output from ALU?

```
 ALU control lines |     Function
-------------------+-------------------
       0000        |       AND
       0001        |       OR
       0010        |       add
       0110        |     subtract
       0111        | set on less than
```

Or is the ALU supposed to output 1 if the result of `A - B` (in `slt $t1, A, B`) is negative.

Comment: What do you mean by "considered an ALU operation"? What else should it be?

Comment: I was thinking the ALU does a subtract and some logic will process using the Zero/Negative output from the ALU

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's supposed to output 1 if A is less than b and 0 otherwise. This often entails calculating A - B, which you need the ALU for.

Now if it was just calculating the sign bit of `A - B` it would be redundant, but consider the case where `A = -2147483648 = 0x80000000` and `B = 1 = 0x00000001`, here the subtraction result will be `0x7fffffff = 2147483647`, which does not have the most significant bit set even though `A < B`.

As the table is from "Patterson, David A.; Hennessy, John L.: Computer Organization and Design" I'll refer you to chapter 3, specifically the subsection that deals with "addition and subtraction" (3.3 in the 2nd edition, 3.2 in the 4th). It has a table dealing with overflow/underflow where the corner cases can be looked up.

Also remember that the ALU result is 32 bits, so even if the result was just the sign bit of the subtraction result it would still need a different ALU operation code to signal that 31 zeros concatenated with the result bit should be returned rather than the full subtraction result.

The "Zero" line you're probably referring to is - in the architectures discussed in the book - IIRC only used for comparisons in relation to branch equal / branch not equal. `SLT/SLTI` on the hand stores its result in a register.

Comment: ic, so what should the ALU output when theres an overflow? The "wrong" result with an **O**verflow bit output set? If so, what is stored in the resister then?

Comment: If we're still talking about SLT/SLTI they should return the appropriate result even if overflow or underflow occurs (31 zeros and then another 0 if !(A<B) and 1 otherwise). Also just saw your comment on the question: There is some logic to handle to handle it, it's just usually placed inside the ALU.